# Undefined Index Array

Tags: php, laravel

I just learning laravel and got this error

[image: route class]

calling array on route class using foreach but i got error (undefined index)
[image: calling array on route class using foreach but i got error (undefined index)]

Comment: Welcome. Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: Compare the variable that contains all posts, and your iteration variable containing one post. On which are you trying to access the "title" element?

Comment: Hi, you use `$posts` instead of `$post` in your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong variable within the foreach scope.

use `$post["title"]` instead of `$posts["title"]`

```
// @foreach ($posts as $post)

$posts: entire array
$post: an item of array
```

Comment: omg its work thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is spelling mistake you should use

```
$post["title"] not $posts["title"]
```